# When an entry is made to table Animal , if the list price is an odd number then add 1 to it and then insert it into the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

```
CREATE TRIGGER CHANGEEVEN ON ANIMAL
AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
     IF LISTPRICE %2!=0
        SET LISTPRICE=LISTPRICE+1
    ELSE
        SET LISTPRICE=LISTPRICE;
END
```

[image]

Comment: You appear to have forgotten to ask a question here. What are you asking? What isn't working and why? What have you tried to fix the problem?

Comment: Why does your trigger not make any references to the `inserted` object?

Comment: Don't forget UPDATE trigger as well.

Comment: its throwing syntax error can you please correct that i cant find the error

Comment: Simplify: SET LISTPRICE = LISTPRICE + (LISTPRICE % 2)

Comment: its showing this error:-" Incorrect syntax near '='. "

Comment: Missing `THEN`? And perhaps also an `END`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an `instead of` trigger.  Your syntax just looks very wrong for SQL Server.  You are not referring to `inserted`.

It should look like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CHANGEEVEN ON ANIMAL
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ANIMAL (LISTPRICE, . . . )  -- list columns here
        SELECT (CASE WHEN LISTPRICE % 2 = 1 THEN LISTPRICE + 1
                     ELSE LISTPRICE
                END),
               . . .   -- rest of columns here
        FROM inserted i;
END;
```